# MS Licensing - 3 windows machines, 30 users, how many CALs required?

Tags: windows-server-2008, licensing

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Can you help me with my software licensing question?](https://serverfault.com/questions/215405/can-you-help-me-with-my-software-licensing-question)

I'm in the middle of upgrading, and purchasing licensing for 3 of our Servers.

One will be a Windows Server 2008 machine, running SQL Server 2008.
The other two machines will be domain controllers, both running Windows 2003.

Our organisation has 30 Users.

I understand (through our reseller) that a Windows 2008 licence gives "downgrade" rights to use 2003.

Realistically, for the above setup of 3 machines, will I just need one set of 30 CALs for 2008?

Answer (score 2):

Correct  30 CALS for 2008 will do the trick.  You will need to pick user or device CAL as well.  You will need SQL licenses as well.  Depends on your SQL license.  [Server 2008 License info](http://www.microsoft.com/windowsserver2008/en/us/client-licensing.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

You can get both User CALs that cover a specific user on any computer that they may use (think execs with a Desktop, Laptop, and WinCE device) or Device CALs that cover any number of users accessing the system from that one device (think common-area computer, shared workstation for multi-shift information workers)

We do a mix of Device and User CALs. We have a few workstations that support 3-5 graphic designers and machine operators with different schedules throughout the week and over 3 shifts a day, these workstations are perfect for Device CALs.

We also have some shared use computers for production floor employees (who also don't have dedicated desktops) to log their time and lookup production information shared by 5-10 different users, we use Device CALs for these as well.

For pretty much everyone else in the company that has a dedicated desktop and/or laptop we use User CALs.

For 30 users this distinction may not be worth the trouble but it saved us a considerable amount of money since over half of our workforce are manufacturing production employees without dedicated workstations.